# PHP regex - add UTF-* characters

Tags: php, regex

I'm learning regular expressions.

I have the following regular expression:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9 +=,?.;:\'\"_()-]+$/m
```

I'm in need to add UTF-8 chatacters to this regex. Adding \w with u modifier does not work - any ideas why?

Comment: Mohammar, `\w` includes a bit more than just letters.

Comment: as you can see he already added numbers and underscore. So no problem with adding \pL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is unclear. If you want to add all unicode charactes to `[...]`, then it will match everything...

If you want to add just some specific unicode, then use `\uXXXX` where `XXXX` is its hex code. But for PHP you need to add `/u` modifier.

Learn more at http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

---

Update: After reading your post several times I believe you are looking for regex

```
/^[\p{L}\p{N} +=,?.;:\'\"_()-]+$/um
```

Comment: I think they want the character class `\w` to be Unicode-aware. The documentation is fairly silent on that, though and doesn't even formally define what `\w` includes :|

Comment: @Joey - Then the best bet would be `^[\p{L}\p{N}]+$/u` I believe. I am not sure if `_` is in `\p{L}`, but it is in `\w`.

Comment: The underscore isn't a letter so it needs to be included explicitly. Also I think `\p{Nd}` is more accurate.

Comment: @Joey - difference is just to exclude ideograms that represent numbers - never ever seen any just hieroglyphs :)

Comment: @Ωmega - thanks - I screw up everything while trying to get it working, thanks for the solution. I'm currently reading the docs and trying to learn regular expressions finally :)